# how to load from JSON and parse into tableView on iOS 5

Tags: ios, json, parsing, ios5, tableview

I have a audio player that streams some links, and I want the links to be loaded into a tableView via JSON.

Heres my tableView that shows the links: (out-commented, but works without json)

```
/*
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    int row = indexPath.row;

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[_radioNames objectAtIndex:row]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[_radioSubtitles objectAtIndex:row]];
    if(row == _currentRadio) {
        [cell setAccessoryView:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"now_playing.png"]] autorelease]];
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryView:nil];
    }


    return cell;
}
 */
```

Heres where I get my JSON file:

```
// Download JSON
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString
                            stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxxxxxxxx/radioliste.json"]
                            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                            error:nil];
    // Create parser
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
    [parser release], parser = nil;
    // Set tableData
    [self setTableData:[results objectForKey:@"items"]];

    NSLog(jsonString); // THIS IS SHOWING ME THE WHOLE JSON FILE, DON'T KNOW IF THAT OK?
```

Heres the JSON datalist:(or so i think)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Change UITableViewCellStyle
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Get item from tableData
    NSDictionary *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    // Set text on textLabel
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[item objectForKey:@"title"]];
    // Set text on detailTextLabel
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[item objectForKey:@"description"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Heres my JSON file:

```
{
    "radioliste": {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "The Voice",
            "string": "Afspil The Voice",
            "string": "LINK"
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

So heres my questions... how do I load my streaming links correct from the JSON file and parse them into the tableView? and is the JSON file even valid?

Comment: No, the JSON is invalid as it has twice the key "string" for the same object. From [json.org](http://json.org/): _An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs._ (and _unordered_ means you can't distinguish which "string" is the link one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use initWithContentsOfURL... That's a blocking call and will freeze your app.  Use NSURLConnection in asynchronous mode to get the data from the network.

Second, NSJSONSerialization has been available since iOS 5.  Use that.

So, NSURLConnection will build up an NSData.  NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: will turn that NSData into an object.  In your case, it will be a NSDictionary.

The JSON file you pasted does not match the object key names you're using in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  I'm not sure what would happen since two of the keys in the first item are "string".  But assuming you meant title & description, you could use something like:

```
cell.textLabel.text = tableData[@"items"][indexPath.row][@"title"];
```

to get the title into the table cell.

Comment: Okay, how do i use the NSJSONSerialization insted of the one i have already ? and shall i just replace initWithContentsOfURL with NSURLConnection ? i know thise might me stupid questions, but i have no idea how to work with JSON

Answer (score 1):

How about using the native JSON library like this:

```
NSData* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];
```

and

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:(__bridge NSData *)data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

instead of SBJSON?

EDIT: Just noticed some issue with your JSON. You have a duplicate key in a dictionary: string.

Comment: You don't use an extra lib that you don't know how well maintained is since there is a native interface for JSON right now.

Comment: Okay, how do i use that insted ?